# Optimistic Concurrency Exception During Synchronous Update Call

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I am attempting to modify a single boolean property on my Invoice entity.
This is my class:

```
public class Invoice : SoftDeletableEntity, IIsActive
{
    public Invoice()
    {
        IsEditable = true;
    }

    [ForeignKey("Booking")]
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    public Booking Booking { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public string OurReference { get; set; }
    public string CustomerReference { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AccountInformation")]
    public int AccountInformationId { get; set; }
    public AccountInformation AccountInformation { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceInformation> ImportantInformation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("InvoiceItem")]
    public List<int> InvoiceItemIds { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceLineItem> InvoiceLineItems { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("InvoiceDocument")]
    public List<int> InvoiceDocumentIds { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceDocument> InvoiceDocuments { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string Terms { get; set; }
    public bool IsReversal { get; set; }
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
    public int? ParentInvoiceId { get; set; }
}
```

These classes are exported as a formatted PDF. That process works quite well, and then I have this code that checks whether or not the PDF was constructed correctly, then if the export succeeds, the code sets the invoice as ineditable like so:

```
    var doc = pdf.CreateInvoicePdf(resultModel, user);
    var bytes = GetPdfBytes(doc);

    if (bytes != null)
    {
        result.IsEditable = false;
    }

    unitOfWork.Commit();
```

When I call this "unitOfWork.Commit();" I get the following exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships.
```

The inner exception:

```
Message "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."
```

The most recently added foreign key reference was for CustomerId, but it is set up just like all of the other foreign keys. I have checked the database for FK = 0 for all foreign key entities and there are no missing references. Also this is running on my local, so I am certain the entity was not modified by sources other than my browser.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible reasons which might cause such problem:

1. You trying to update entity with primary key `Id == 0` or another `default` value (`Guid.Empty` or `string.Empty`). So, verify that Id is set properly.
2. When you try to create a new object and tell EF that it's modified using the `EntityState.Modified`. Then it will throw this error as it doesn't yet exist in the database. So, try to use `EntityState.Added`.
3. You tried to update or delete a row but the row doesn't exist.

Comment: SoftDeletableEntity contains the Primary Key field (Id), which is inherited for all entities. I have double checked now that it is never null or 0.

Comment: I see that you have many references => check that all your foreign key Id is also not 0. Then, check if you do not add new entities with EntityState.Modified.

Comment: One more thing: it can happen if entity which you want to update - was deleted before updating. So also you can check that entity exists before trying to update it. This also applies to all referenced entities (foreign key).